# Disable editing for SWTableViewCell

Tags: uitableview

I would like to know if it is possible to disable editing for SWTableViewCell´s, something like:

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is as simple as NOT assigning to `cell.rightUtilityButtons` on the cells you don't want to be swipable (or setting them to `nil` after assignment).

The library will detect whether there are any available buttons to show and if none exist will not allow the pan gesture.